# using both call(this) and passing the event object to stop propogation

Tags: jquery

I have a small piece of jQuery like this:

```
$('.remove-header').on('click',function(){
  arc.event_handler.remove_header_click.call(this);
});
```

The .remove-header is nested within a similar object so I need to call event.stopPropogation but normally I'd pass a reference like this:

```
$('.remove-header').on('click',function(event){
  arc.event_handler.remove_header_click(event);
});
```

How would I combine both of these into a call? The couple things I have tried haven't seemed to work.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the `event` object can simply be done by passing it as additional argument to `.call`:

```
$('.remove-header').on('click',function(event){
  arc.event_handler.remove_header_click.call(this, event);
});
```

Have a look at [the documentation for `.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

But you can also directly stop the propagation inside the event handler like [jfriend00 showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11855525/218196).

Comment: @timpone: Don't be sorry for asking, only be sorry for not reading the documentation ;)

Comment: yeah, well, the docs rarely seem to be my friend but agreed. that one would have come up. still waiting to accept answer. thx again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I know what you're asking, but can't you just do this:

```
$('.remove-header').on('click',function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     arc.event_handler.remove_header_click.call(this, event);
});
```